# Find duplicate data in last 1 hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am looking for a SQL script to find the data which has more than 2 entries in last 1 hour.
I have a table having user_id & event_time. I want a way to find out if the user_id has more than 1 entries in last 1 hour.

I have tried below till now:

1. Create temp table to put all duplicate entries :

```
SELECT a.*
INTO #temp 
FROM Table a
JOIN (
    SELECT USERID, COUNT(*) AS Duplicates
    FROM Table
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) AS b ON a.userid = b.USERID
```

2. Run self Joins to fetch records having time difference of 1 hour or less:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM #temp a
INNER JOIN #temp b ON a.userid = b.USERID
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour, a.EVENTTIME, b.EVENTTIME) = 1
```

Once first script is ran it gives around 800+ rows for duplicate data. But after running the second script the data I get is in thousands.
Can anyone help here?

Comment: the first script gives all duplicates (800+) second script limits it to those whose multiple entries was within the hour

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the expected result

Comment: We need a [mre] with sample data, desired results, actual results and your query.

Comment: So the basic requirement is this:
lets say i have user id which is having multiple entries for the event_time throughout the day. I want to filter out only the entries where time difference between events is less than 1 hour.

Comment: @Rathore if you have events that extend throughout the day, and the time difference between all neighboring events is less than one hour, should you delete them all in this case?

Comment: Aside: Note that [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns the number of _boundary crossings_ based on the specified unit, e.g. `hour`. There is one `hour` boundary between `02:59` and `03:01`. Similarly there is one between `02:01` and `03:59`. There are _none_ between `03:01` and `03:59`. That doesn't look like what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cross apply` can be used to get all related events for each event according to your criteria as follows:

```
With CTE As (
Select USERID, EVENTTIME, Row_Number() Over (Order by USERID, EVENTTIME) As ID
From Tbl
)
Select a.ID, a.USERID, a.EVENTTIME, T.ID, T.USERID, T.EVENTTIME
From CTE As a Cross Apply (Select ID, USERID, EVENTTIME 
                           From CTE 
                           Where Abs(datediff(minute, a.EVENTTIME, EVENTTIME))<=60
                                 And USERID=a.USERID And ID<>a.ID) As T
Order by a.ID, a.USERID, a.EVENTTIME, T.ID, T.USERID, T.EVENTTIME
```

or you can get a list of events without binding to a specific event:

```
With CTE As (
Select USERID, EVENTTIME, Row_Number() Over (Order by USERID, EVENTTIME) As ID
From Tbl
)
Select T.USERID, T.EVENTTIME
From CTE As a Cross Apply (Select USERID, EVENTTIME 
                           From CTE 
                           Where Abs(datediff(minute, a.EVENTTIME, EVENTTIME))<=60
                                 And USERID=a.USERID And ID<>a.ID) As T
Group by T.USERID, T.EVENTTIME
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f80c6cbdd43f427bda7487842af5af8e)

to get the events only for last hour, you can add the appropriate filter to `Where` clause in `CTE`.

```
With CTE As (
Select USERID, EVENTTIME, Row_Number() Over (Order by USERID, EVENTTIME) As ID
From Tbl
Where EVENTTIME Between dateadd(minute, -60, GetDate()) And GetDate()
)
Select T.USERID, T.EVENTTIME
From CTE As a Cross Apply (Select USERID, EVENTTIME 
                           From CTE 
                           Where Abs(datediff(minute, a.EVENTTIME, EVENTTIME))<=60
                                 And USERID=a.USERID 
                                 And ID<>a.ID) As T
Group by T.USERID, T.EVENTTIME
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a row number for each group of `user_id` in the order of date difference in hours. Remember to filter the rows which have the `event_date` in last 1 hour.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by [user_id]
        order by [user_id], datediff(hour, [event_time], getdate())
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
    where datediff(hour, [event_time], getdate()) < 2
)
select * from [your_table_name] as [t1]
where exists(
    select 1 from cte as [t2]
    where [t1].[user_id]= [t2].[user_id]
    and [t2].[rn] > 1
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!
I will try to test it out.